# I am trying to write VBA code that will remove all rows after the last row of data but only within a certain range of rows

Tags: excel, vba, delete-row

I cannot find a good solution that will only delete rows after the last row of data but stops at a certain row.  After row 3000 I have some legal language that needs to stay.  So, I only want to delete all rows from the last line to row 3000.  I have tried this:

```
On Error Resume Next
Range("A5:A3000").Select
Selection.SpecialCells(x1CellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
```

But it is not deleting the rows, probably because it is not identifying blank cells correctly.

Comment: `x1CellTypeBlanks` should be `xlCellTypeBlanks` with a lower case `L` not the number `1`

Comment: Geez...I looked at that for a long time and couldn't figure it out...Thanks!